# how to instantiate a js object from .json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, instantiation

I have included my json file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshows/1/myfile.json"></script>
```

And I wonder how I can now create a js object from this file?

If the json was defined inline, or defined in a .js-file it would already have a variable connected to it, but how does it work now that it is in a separate json file?

Comment: I would use `jQuery - getJSON( url, [data], [callback] )` to call json file and instantiate in callback method

Comment: JSON is `application/json` not `application/javascript`. It isn't a programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSON file is not a script. It is data.

You need to use a data access method, such as jQuery's `$.getJSON()` to get it.

Comment: And loading it over such an ajax call will still utilise the cached version of myfile.json as long as it is included in the cache manifest am I right?

Comment: I'm not an expert on caching rules, but that sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

Using script tags to import `JSON` in the page has only on useful use case, which is a way to prevent `Cross-origin` security issue from happening. We use it as `JSONP` in JavaScript by sending a callback attribute on the query-string:

```
<script type="text/javascript"">
    window.getMyJSON = function(json){

    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://someotherdomain/slideshows/1/myfile.json?callback=getMyJSON">
</script>
```

**BUT** it seems here the JSON file is located just on the current domain, so as @Scimonster has pointed out you can simply achieve it using `$.getJSON()`.